# Missing type for XML Fact in JDeveloper 11g BPEL rule manager

Tags: oracle, soa, oracle11g, jdeveloper, bpel

I'm currently working on a composite for the Oracle SOA Suite 11g R1. In short, I have the following BPEL process (some activities not mentioned):

1. File Adapter waiting for XML files (format defined in `input.xsd`) to start an instance. For the example, the input file contains a list of simplistic shopping orders (the XSD type is `Order_Type`).
2. Transform (format defined in `output.xsd`)
3. File Adapter to write output.

Both XSD's use a third `common.xsd` for common types.

I'd like to insert a rule right after reading my input file. From the JDeveloper (11g R1 PS2) BPEL editor, I drag a *Business Rule* activity below my *Receive* activity and use the wizard to create a new Dictionary:

- I let JDeveloper generate XML Facts from my `input.xsd`. `Order_Type` gets marshalled to the class `mypackage.OrderType` with selector `//xs:complexType[@name='Order_Type']`
- I create a new Ruleset, and a new rule taking an order as input.
- I create a Decision Function to call that rule. The function has one input parameter of type `OrderType`

If I close the function dialog now, I have no error but cannot select the rule in my BPEL process.

On the other hand, if I select *Will Be Invoked As A Webservice* then close, I have the following error message:

> Element not found in XML-Schema file.
>   The element for fact type mypackage.OrderType could not be found in XML Schema file file:/C:/Jdeveloper/[...]/xsd/input.xsd [...]

aka [BPM-36355](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/core.1111/e10113/chapter_bpm_messages.htm) error, although that error code is not explicitly mentioned.

Of course, the type is present in the file (as I said, I let JDev generate the JAXB classes for me), so I'm at a loss as to why this error happens, or how to correct it.

I tried various combinations for the generation of XML facts, of the decision function, and I restarted JDev (don't laugh, that actually fixed a weird issue yesterday), but to no avail. The XPath expression selecting the type is correct.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Except dropping Oracle or downgrading to pre-11g, of course.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My root element, `Order`, was a sequence of `Order_Type`. I solved the issue described above by using `Order` instead of `Order_Type` for my decision function parameter. The WSDL was generated successfully, and my rule is called.

I don't know whether this is a bug or a feature so if anyone has more information, feel free to post it.